What are the actual GIF requirements?
Recently, the image hosting was changed (New service failing on .gif uploads) and now sometimes I have troubles uploading a .gif:


Image uploads are limited to 50 megapixels; please use a smaller image

So what does it mean exactly? Width × height × number of frames?
Here are two examples of gifs I failed to upload:
Align Vertices (constantly changing locations)

How to make Spiral in Geometry nodes [ but without node spiral ]

You can download these gifs and try to reupload them to reproduce the issue. The way I embedded these gifs there is using an <img> tag:
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/7DqAAp8.gif">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/NgTA9UU.gif">

However, I know embedding images like that is problematic, for example some visitors to this site have the Imgur domain blocked. It's just that using gifs was already introducing a lot of friction given the harsh 2 MB limit. There's also some compatibility issues (or used to be), that made it impossible to upload gifs after optimizing them in some software, so there's at least 3 separate requirements for uploading gifs.

"Width × height × number of frames?" This was also my uninformed guess, both image size and number of frames counts towards total pixel count somehow, I've also been encountering that error. According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/399146/334476 there was an intentional pixel size limit added to prevent delays. Not sure what to make of it, the limitation seems restrictive and undesirable, but not a really bug strictly speaking. I'll tag this as [feature-request] for now, see if we can convince @slate to up the limit

Width × height × number of frames definitely seems to be it. I had a 400kB gif with 288 frames of 175,420 pixels each (that comes to 50,520,960 pixels) and got this error. I dropped about 7 frames to be safe, bringing it to 49,293,020 pixels…but I also increased the number of colors, bringing the total file size to ~750kB. The new, larger file was able to be uploaded. If the limit is actually useful, I don't mind it being in place…but it needs a more clear error message.

This is really annoying. Cannot share GIFs... Those were useful...

Based on my initial guess and a confirmation in comments and my experience, the animated GIF/APNG requirements are:

maximum of 2 MB file size;
maximum of 50 000 000 pixels counted across all frames: width × height × number of frames;
the file shouldn't use fringe settings, so using the best APNG/GIF compressors will produce a GIF that can be opened in a browser but won't be accepted by Stack Exchange.

Here's how I fix my GIFs:

Upload my GIF to Ezgif.com - unfortunately it can no longer read imgur links, so you need to upload a file from your computer; for those who use ShareX, dragging a thumbnail from ShareX onto the website works.
Below uploaded GIF, notice size info, e.g.


File size: 3.77MiB, width: 307px, height: 474px, frames: 542


Open a calculator, multiply dimensions together to get 1 frame area, then divide 50000000 by that area, this gives you the number of frames you need to decrease your GIF to.

$$307 × 474 = 145 518$$
$$50.000.000 ÷ 145 518 = 343.6001044544318$$
So you need to reduce the GIF to 343 frames

If you need to reduce the count of frames by a lot, consider cropping, resizing, or in the worst case, cutting the GIF by moving the end near the half, remembering where it is, and uploading another GIF that you cut by moving the start to the same time.

In Optimization settings, choose "Drop Frames: Remove every 2nd frame", click "Optimize GIF!"

In Optimization settings again, choose "Drop Frames: Remove duplicate frames". Repeatedly choose a "Fuzz" setting, and click "Optimize GIF!" until you find the setting that reduces the number of frames below calculated threshold.

You can right-click the generated GIF, copy image link, and use that on SE to embed an image.

If you also link to a mirror (because SE image hosting has problems), upload the original GIF to Imgur, rather than linking to Ezgif. If a lot of people load the image from Ezgif, the IP originally uploading the file will get banned! Of course when you use the link to upload an image on Stack Exchange, it creates its copy, so it's fine.



late to the party but I guess there could be some way to somewhat automate this or at least make the optimization have less trials to do?
